# Android - how can I create a service that listens to speech?

Tags: android, android-service

Does Android allow to run a Siri type app that runs in the background (with a service, every time the user turns on his phone, without the user opening the app) and listens to the users and then performs actions based on their speech?

Comment: Can you? Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

Here we have a library called [gast-lib](https://github.com/gast-lib/gast-lib) that check device sensors and something that you wanna do is here [SpeechActivationService](https://github.com/gast-lib/gast-lib/blob/master/library/src/root/gast/speech/activation/SpeechActivationService.java)

check it out, hope it help ;)

Comment: Thanks. Can this run in the background without the users actively opening the app in the first place?

Comment: yes, it's implementation is based on a service, so it can be run in background